# Зависимые друг от друга библиотеки, или forward declaration of type

Tags: c#, .net

Как поступить в ситуации когда обе библиотеки `.NET` зависят от одного или более типов расположенных в разных библиотеках?

В `c++` есть `forward declaration`, как быть с `c#`? Ведь они не могут ссылаться друг на друга т.к. эта циклическая зависимость.

Comment: В C# придется вынести часть типов в 3-ю библиотеку. Forward declaration нет.

Comment: Нужно создать сборку, на которую будут ссылаться две другие. И там объявить общие типы.

Comment: А что если это `COM` интерфейсы, и мне не стоило бы определять их в сторонней библиотеке?